# How to pass in argument of type DATE to a function

Tags: oracle, delphi, delphi-7

I've got a function in an oracle database. I need to call it from delphi. I use the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.Run;
var
 q:TADOQuery;
begin
 q:=TADOQuery.Create(nil);
 q.Connection:=ADOConnection1;
 q.ParamCheck:=false;

 q.SQL.Add('BEGIN');
 q.SQL.Add(' :RES:=Search(:P_DATE);');
 q.SQL.Add('END;');

 q.Parameters.AddParameter.Name:='P_DATE';
 q.Parameters.ParamByName('P_DATE').Direction:=pdInput;
 q.Parameters.ParamByName('P_DATE').DataType:=ftDate;
 q.Parameters.ParamByName('P_DATE').Value:=Now;
 q.Parameters.AddParameter.Name:='RES';
 q.Parameters.ParamByName('RES').DataType:=ftFloat;
 q.Parameters.ParamByName('RES').Direction:=pdOutput;
 q.Parameters.ParamByName('RES').Value:=1;

 q.ExecSQL;
 //...
```

I get `ora-06550` error, saying `invalid number or type of parameters`. If I change the `P_DATE` parameter to `sysdate`, i.e. `:RES:=Search(sysdate);`, it works fine.

So how can I pass an "in" parameter of type `DATE` to an oracle function from delphi?

---

Found [ORA-06550 when Oracle stored function is called.](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=3413). However this relates to Kylix Pascal IDE. Am I expected to meet the same behaviour for delphi? Didn't try to use oracle procedure instead of a function. Maybe this issue can be solved some how else...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle doesn't have a date type for bind variables - you need to explicitly convert the bind variable to a date:

```
:res := search(to_date(:p_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
```

You should then be able to pass your variable as a string matching the date format you've specified.

Comment: When I use this I get ora-01840, saying _input value not long enough for date format_ What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also it does not pass the function result code into `RES` parameter

Comment: The string you're passing as a date doesn't match the format given (in to_date). For example, to pass 29 Dec 2012 using the format mask I've used above the string must be 29/12/2012. The string you're using must be shorter than the mask supplied.

Comment: Actually I passed `'YYYYMMDD'` format and set the value of parameter with `FormatDateTime('YYYYMMDD',Now)`. So how can they differ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to send this parameter as a string:

```
 .........
 q.SQL.Add('BEGIN');
 q.SQL.Add(' :RES:=Search(TO_DATE(:P_DATE,''YYYYMMDD''));');
 q.SQL.Add('END;');

 q.Parameters.AddParameter.Name:='P_DATE';
 q.Parameters.ParamByName('P_DATE').Direction:=pdInput;
 q.Parameters.ParamByName('P_DATE').DataType:=ftString;
 q.Parameters.ParamByName('P_DATE').Value:=FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd',Now);
 ..........
```

Comment: When I use this I get ora-01840, saying _input value not long enough for date format_ What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also it does not pass the function result code into `RES` parameter

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong (and I think you had a previous question deleted as being a duplicate that asked this same question (different function, but same idea) just a couple of days ago).

You're calling the function wrong in the first place.

```
.........
q.SQL.Add('BEGIN');
q.SQL.Add('  SELECT Search(TO_DATE(:P_DATE,''YYYYMMDD'')) FROM System.Dual;');
q.SQL.Add('END;');

q.Parameters.AddParameter.Name:='P_DATE';
q.Parameters.ParamByName('P_DATE').Direction:=pdInput;
q.Parameters.ParamByName('P_DATE').DataType:=ftDate;
q.Parameters.ParamByName('P_DATE').Value:=Now;
q.Open;

if not q.IsEmpty then     // or not q.Eof
  Res := q.Fields[0].AsFloat;
```

Comment: IMHO you have to Open and not ExecSQL to get a resultset

Comment: @SirRufo: Yep, you're right. I copied/pasted from the original question, and missed that when making my changes. Fixed, and thanks for pointing it out. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite when I use the sql syntax you suggesst, I get ORA-06572 error, saying _PL/SQL functions referenced by SQL statements must not contain the OUT parameter._ How should I overcome that problem? And why do you say, that the syntax posted in the original question is wrong? Oracle says nothing about that and does the job actually

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov - could you post the definition of the `search` function in your question please; it seems like you have out parameters in the function, which means you can't use the select ... from approach. Your original method of `:res := search()` is valid Oracle syntax so should work.

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov: You keep telling us "it won't work", but you're not giving us any information to use to try and help you. Please edit your question to include the actual definition of the function you're calling, because we can't help any further without it.